# I want to get a specific value from a data frame and see what another value is a few rows down , but in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame now3:

```
           size                date          unix   price
0           4.0 2019-11-03 02:42:00  1.570000e+12  9288.5
1           4.0 2019-11-03 02:42:00  1.570000e+12  9288.5
2           4.0 2019-11-03 02:42:00  1.570000e+12  9288.5
3           4.0 2019-11-03 02:42:00  1.570000e+12  9288.5
4           4.0 2019-11-03 02:42:00  1.570000e+12  9288.5
...         ...                 ...           ...     ...
1048570    15.0 2019-11-05 05:48:00  1.570000e+12  9331.0
1048571  3851.0 2019-11-05 05:48:00  1.570000e+12  9331.0
1048572  3793.0 2019-11-05 05:48:00  1.570000e+12  9331.0
1048573  1000.0 2019-11-05 05:48:00  1.570000e+12  9331.0
1048574   200.0 2019-11-05 05:48:00  1.570000e+12  9331.0
```

I want to see what the price is at a certain size but 5 minutes later. For example at size 4 I want to see what the value of the price is but 5 minutes later.

I have the following code right now, and am having trouble get that certain data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
%matplotlib inline
headers = ['ticker', 'size', 'price', 'unix','type','date']
dtypes = {'ticker': 'str', 'size': 'float', 'price': 'float', 'unix': 'float','type': 'str','date': 'str'}
parse_dates = ['date']
btcnow = pd.read_csv('new 113-115.csv', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)
now3 = pd.DataFrame(btcnow, columns=['size','date','unix','price'])
x1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 24022, "date"]
y1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 24022, "size"]
```

This can either be done using unix time or the date-time. (5 minutes is 300 unix).

The expected output format should be the price of that size in 5 minutes. For example of size 4 , it is 2:42 I want to know the price at 2:47. So, the  output will be the price at 2:47. However, there is more than one size 4 in the data, so it should output the current time and price and the price in 5 min in next to each size 4. 
Example of wanted output:

```
size                date             Date +5             Price(in 5)
4           4.0 2019-11-03 02:42:00  2019-11-03 02:42:00  9278.5
4           4.0 2019-11-03 02:49:00  2019-11-03 02:54:00  9288
```

I tried the following:

```
d1= now3.loc[(now3["size"] == 24022) & (now3["date"]+pd.Timedelta('5 minutes')), "price"]
```

But it gives me an error

Comment: what is now3 and what is now4?

Comment: That was an extra data frame, I edited the code. The data frame above is now3.

Comment: Would you mind provide the expected output format?

Comment: Yep I added an extra line above in the description for the output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, it uses timedelta to modify the original time to get the desired ones, then store it in a separate dataframe. Inner join the desired (time, size) pairs with all the data, you will get the data you want.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_interval = timedelta(minutes = 5)
df = df[[ 'time', 'size', 'price']]

# extract time size for merge
df_time_size= df[['time', 'size']]
df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] = df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] + time_interval

# inner join dataframe by size&time
df = df_time_size.merge(df[['time', 'size', 'price']], how = 'inner')
df['orig_time'] = df['time'] - time_interval
```

Out put will be like:

```
                   time size  price            orig_time
0   2019-01-01 12:26:00    1      3  2019-01-01 12:21:00
1   2019-01-01 12:27:00    1      1  2019-01-01 12:22:00
```

Edit:

In order to get the latest price, we can do groupby, then sort(descending) by time, then get the first row.

```
df = df.groupby('size').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time', ascending=False).head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I just output the last price, instead of all the prices for that size?

Comment: @MonicaW you want one record per size? for the latest?

Comment: Also, how would I be able to add an original price column as well?

Comment: Yes, so instead of all the prices find the last price for that time. As, seen in your example, for size 1 it would print $1 because that was the last price. Or do the average of the prices, whichever is possible.

Comment: They are both achievable. Please see my edit for latest.